# Writing tests to verify passing a function as argument in Scala

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have something like this:

```
def fnA(argA: Int, argB: Int, argC: Int): Seq[Int] = {
   tryRequest {
     ...
   }
}

def tryRequest[T](f: => T): T = {
    try {
        f
    } catch {
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to test this with Mockito/ScalaTest. I want to either make sure that 1. my return type is what I expect it to be (Seq[Int] when I call fnA), or 2. that I am passing in the right type to tryRequest when I'm calling it ((Int, Int, Int) => Seq[Int] when I call fnA). I've tried variations of:

```
exampleInstance.fnA(1, 2, 3)
there was one(exampleInstance).tryRequest(any)
```

but I always get something like

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
    exampleInstance.tryRequest(
        ($anonfun$apply$17) <function0>
    );

Actual invocation has different arguments:
    exampleInstance.tryRequest(
        ($anonfun$fnA$1) <function0>
    );
```

Any ideas how I can accurately test this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using ScalaTest or specs2? Could that be an instance of this case: http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Byname?

Comment: I'm using ScalaTest!

Comment: I didn't realise you could write `there was` with ScalaTest. I've only seen http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.1/#org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar on top of Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're passing where - you seem to think you're passing a `(Int, Int, Int) => Seq[Int]` to `tryRequest`, but the definition of `fnA` you give isn't doing that (it's already taken the `Int` arguments before it calls `tryRequest`). But going by what you've written rather than the code:

It's generically impossible to compare functions for equality, and that syntax will "really" create an anonymous wrapper (do you really need the laziness of the `=> T` given that you're passing a function in there anyway?), thus the failures. What you can do is confirm that the function that was passed to the inner call has some of the same properties as the function you already passed. I don't know the fancy syntax, but with an ordinary Java testing/mocking library I'd do something like:

```
val myCaptor = capture[=> ((Int, Int, Int) => Seq[Int])]
expect(exampleInstance.tryRequest(myCaptor.capture()))

exampleInstance.fnA({(a, b, c) => a + b + c})

val functionThatWasPassed = myCaptor.getValue()
assertThat(functionThatWasPassed(3, 4, 5)) isEqualTo 12
assertThat(functionThatWasPassed(-1, 0, 2)) isEqualTo 1
```